# .NET get variable value inside HTML attribute

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is my first time using .NET so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to change the value of the `class` atribute in a HTML element, depending on some `if/else` statements, like so:

```
@if (item.HasAir)
{
    var icon = "fa fa-plane";
    var circleColour = "icon-bg-blue";
}
else if (item.HasCar)
{
    var icon = "fa fa-car";
    var circleColour = "icon-bg-cyan";
}

<span class="icon-cirle @circleColour" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="@icon"></span>
</span>
```

However when refreshing the page in my browser, I'm getting a `Compilation Error`:

> The name 'circleColour' does not exist in the current context

Looking at the code above, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

#### Other info:

- .NET Framework version: **4.0.x**
- ASP.NET version: **4.7.x**

Comment: Your icon and circleColor variables are scoped inside the if statements - that is, they are out of scope when you reference them in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I didn't initially declare a default value, in case the if/elseif statements weren't met, which in my case, they weren't.

The following seemed to solve the issue:

```
@{
    var icon = "fa fa-plane";
    var circleColour = "icon-bg-blue";
}

@if (item.HasCar)
{
    icon = "fa fa-car";
    circleColour = "icon-bg-cyan";
}
...
```